# How to mock set state and method from protected abstracts method in React Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

This is how the components are arranged

```
class A extends React.Component {
  state = {mode: 'create'}

  abstract getRows() {
    
  }

  abstract getTitle(){
     
  }
}

class B extends A {
   getTitle(){
     if(this.state.mode === 'create'){ return 'New';}
     else {return 'Existing'};
   }
}
```

And in test case:

```
jest.mock('componentAFile');

component = shallow(<B />);

component.setState({mode: 'create'});
expect(component.instance().getTitle()).toBe('New');

component.setState({mode: 'edit'});
expect(component.instance().getTitle()).toBe('Existing');
```

But state mode says undefined. What is the correct way to do this? How do we test such classes inheriting from base classes?

Answer (score 0):

First, better [don't use](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) that inheritance approach. Composition is so many way better that I even cannot recall any cons of inheritance.

Second, using `.setState` you are literally accessing internal aka private data. Or in other words "implementation details". There are so many cases when it breaks suddenly(renamed property in `this.state`, refactored class component into function, decompose one component into several etc etc), that there are no reason to use it.

Third, the same is with testing internal methods. Again, it's implementation details, for both name, arguments ordering, result returned. And moreover, let's assume you *never* use that function in what component renders in `render()`. So test will pass, but component might be broken.

What can you do instead?

1. Provide prop(`shallow(<B prop1={mockedValue} prop2={anotherValue} />);`)
2. change prop(`.setProps`)
3. call callback(`component.find('button').simulate('click')`)
4. validate against rendering results: `expect(component.find('.title').text()).toBe('New')`
5. also we may want to validate whether some mocked external service/utility has been called(but your case probably does not need that; just want to have complete list)

Comment: thank you for your response. I definitely agree with you. But unfortunately, the implementation cannot be changed now as its widely used across projects. And the solution that you are offering is component testing which doesn't help for coverage report. I could easily simulate the things with component testings with renderer, react testing library. But this doesnt help with CI-CD report. Any other solution you can suggest for temporary fix?

Comment: What do you mean? Code coverage will be the same, either you call `instance().setState()` or provide prop/mock related 3rd party calls/stimulate events. Or, well, there is one case: when function is never been called during render, conditionally or unconditionally. Is it the case? If yes, what prevents you from deleting dead code instead of making unit test for it?